# Octave installation failed on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, octave

I tried to install octave using

```
sudo apt-get install octave
```

and I met with the following error

```
Setting up octave (3.8.2-4) ...
error: couldn't read directory /usr/local/share/octave/packages: No such file or directory
error: called from
    rebuild at line 29 column 7
    pkg at line 505 column 25
dpkg: error processing package octave (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 octave
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then I tried to install it using

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:octave/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install octave
```

but again the same error. What could be the possible reason? I am new to ubuntu and finding it hard. I have searched enough but this problem is not being solved

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if the folder /usr/local/share/octave/packages exist and if yes try to delete it ( with root) and restart the installation ( to delete a folder with a shell type :sudo rm -r "'name of folder"

Answer (score 0):

Try first  *sudo apt-get autoclean* :

```
sudo apt-get install octave-control octave-image octave-io octave-optim octave-signal octave-statistics
```